# has ScalaTest an or matcher, testing with PlaySpec Playframework and Scala

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, scalatest

I am writing some test in playspec and I want like to write a matcher like this

```
planPromise.trialPeriodDays mustBe (equal (planRequest.trialPeriodDays) or be (None))
```

What the matcher is trying to do is to identify if the value is an int (previously defined) or none.

Obviosly is not working.

Is there a way to write this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout ScalaTest guide here: http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers
and search for "Logical expressions with and and or"

here is an example copied from there

```
option should (equal (Some(List(1, 2, 3))) or be (None))
```

I guess your problem here is using `mustBe` instead of `must`

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz, the answer was this planPromise.trialPeriodDays must (be(planRequest.trialPeriodDays) or be (None))